# Could not write rows in excel

Tags: grails, export

This is my code to export data in excel. I users list is not empty.

def exportExcel(){

```
        if(params?.type && params.type != "html"){

            response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.type]
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=cdsadminlist.${params.extension}")

            List fields = ["username", "email"]
            Map labels = ["username":"User Name", "email":"Email"]

            def upperCase = { domain, value ->
                return value.toUpperCase()
            }

            Map parameters = [title: "cds admin list", "column.widths":[0.15, 0.4]]
            Map formatters = [:]
            List users = userService.cdsAdminList()

            exportService.export(params.type, response.outputStream, users, fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
        }

    }
```

And this is my code to get users

def cdsAdminList() {

```
    def users = UserRole.createCriteria().list{
            or{
                eq("role",Role.findByAuthority(CdsStaticPath.StaticRoles.ROLE_CDSUSER))
                eq("role",Role.findByAuthority(CdsStaticPath.StaticRoles.ROLE_AGENTADMIN))
                eq("role",Role.findByAuthority(CdsStaticPath.StaticRoles.ROLE_REPORTVIEWER))
            }
    }

    def userList = []
    users.each {user->
        if(user.user.enabled){
            userList.add(user)
        }
    }

    return userList
}
```

The excel shows empty rows
[image]

Help me resolve this issue.

Comment: what is the ExportService you are using? Also have you checked with any debugging method that the userService.cdsAdminList() returns some users to you?

Comment: I am using export plugin version 2. Yes I printed the list size. It was not empty.

Comment: your cdsAdminList method can be more groovy with:
  
    return users.findAll {user->
        user.user.enabled}
    }

Comment: Thanks @JorgeAguileraGonzalez

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails failed to export Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094533/grails-failed-to-export-excel)

Answer (score 1):

Found it!!!

You iterate with UserRole object who contain a User object. You must to add to the list the `user`object:

```
if(user.user.enabled){
  userList.add(user.user)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jorge.                                                                                                  
Instead of making changes in userList I changed field List. i.e      
List fields = ["user.username", "user.email"]

Answer (score 0):

Does your *User* domain the *email* attribute ? not sure but if you set attributes you don't have into your domain it can fail silence

Comment: Yes Jorge User domain has email attribute.